# Feed gdb stdin with multiple inputs from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, gdb

This has been driving me crazy and it must be so simple! I've looked at many solutions but none seems to work with my application.

I'm debugging a program in gdb. The program takes two inputs like this:

```
pwndbg> run
Starting program: app.html
what is your name?
foo
Wait, who were you again?
bar
kthxbye
```

Above, the user inputs were `foo` and `bar`. I want to be able to control those two inputs from a file, multiple files, python output, whatever. As long as I can put in hex values, I'm happy.

Among other things, I've tried `r < input1.txt ; input2.txt` where `input.txt` contains `foo` and `input2.txt` contains `bar`, but that just puts `foo` into the input but never `bar`. I've also tried a single file with inputs separated by (appropriate) line breaks, but still only get the first input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you run the program outside of `gdb` with the redirection?:  `program-name < input.txt`?  What behavior do you see there?  Please edit your question and include that output.

Comment: The thing is most probably more complicated than that, but could you please try running your program with `r < <(echo foo; sleep .2; echo bar)`?

Comment: @AndyDalton sadly, since this program doesn't give any feedback about the input, I can't know outside gdb if the input is stored in the program

Comment: @mosvy that did the trick! I had to make the sleep longer. Strange, only 10 lines of code are executed between each input, I wouldn't expect this behavior. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: For a more complete solution, you can use `expect` and the `tty` command of gdb. Or probably set the `SHELL` environment variable to some wrapper. I'll put up a complete answer when I get time.

Comment: It's not just the time between the two read()s in your program, but also the whole time the shell takes to start then your program, for gdb to load the symbols, etc -- everything up to the 2nd read().

Comment: I'll read up on expect and tty, sounds interesting. In the meantime, to read from a file, this should work, right? `r < <(cat input1.txt; sleep 3; cat input2.txt)`? Instead of waiting, this puts the output of both files into the first stdin.

Comment: `r < <(sleep 3; cat input1.txt input2.txt)` would probably work too.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. Suppose `input1.txt` contains `foo` and `input2.txt` contains `bar`. As in the original question, I'd like `foo` to be fed the program after the first prompt and `bar` fed after the second prompt. Right now the first prompt is being fed `foobar` even when I do `r < <(cat input1.txt; sleep 3; cat input2.txt)`

Comment: Your `input1.txt` probably has no terminating newline. It should make no difference whatsoever if it's `echo foo`  or `cat foo.txt`, where `foo.txt` contains just `foo<newline>`.

Comment: btw, please add a `@mosvy` if you want your comments to reach me. this site's broken and I guess that it's AndyDalton which gets your comments instead of me.

Comment: Can you tell us what program you're running?